# React keeps aborting installation when I try the tutorial

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I was trying to follow the tutorial on the react website today but for whatever reason it doesnt want to work for me when i run the command:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

`I get the following error message;

```
Creating a new React app in D:\NodeJs\react\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...


npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for postcss@^7.0.11
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'autoprefixer'
npm ERR! notarget

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\matth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-01- 
12T17_55_39_805Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react- 
 scripts has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-app/ from D:\NodeJs\react
Done.`
```

My npm version is 6.5.0 and Node is 11.6.0

Not sure what the heck is going on as when I did this on my work laptop it worked without any issues with the exact same versions of node and npm

Comment: did you install other packages via `npm` on your `D:` drive? When did yout try this on your work laptop? Both are using windows? And may `D:` be an exteral harddisc?

Comment: I tried it this morning on my work laptop, no issues. I'm reinstalling node on my home computer. Even after uninstalling and reinstalling node it gave me same error

Comment: and windows is also running on that laptop? whats with my other questions?

Comment: try using yarn...does it produce the same error?

Comment: Win 10 on both laptops.

Comment: it should work now as postcss  just got updated to version 7.0.11. https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss

Comment: Ill give it another try, Im jsut fresh installing node one more time

Comment: @MurliPrajapati same issue. yarn gives me same issue. its my weekend no worries, I'm done for the day

Comment: mine solved by using it not on any external hard-disk ,ie, creating folder on desktop and then running it

Answer (score 1):

I was fix problem when I error `create-react-app`

```
Err: code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

I had rename file `.npmrc` --> `.npmrc-old`

```
 C:\Users\you\.npmrc
```

And I success >>> I feel perfect

### -

- 
- 
- 

Or can you fix:
--> use `git bash` terminal

Answer (score 0):

Just an update for everyone. It worked now. All I did was reinstall nodejs for the 4th time, nothing else. Makes 0 sense. anyways, thanks for your answers, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I also got a same error.

Try to run npm cache clean --force after that just run create-react-app

Definitely It will work